Why can't I use my existing /home partition on a separate HD when installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS?
I am performing a fresh installation of Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS on a small SSD connected to an Intel DH67GD mainboard. My previous installation (Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS) had /home on a separate HD, which I would like to continue to use as /home in the new installation.
I have created a bootable USB from the Ubuntu Studio download using Rufus 4.5. I can use it partition my SSD (sda) as desired and install Ubuntu on it.
However, when installing (regardless of whether I use the BIOS or UEFI boot option) I am unable to designate my /home drive as having a my /home partition. In fact, it looks as though the installer fails to recognise the format of the drive (sdc).  IAC, it insists on creating /home under / and gives me no opportunity to specify that it should be on a different HD, much less to preserve an existing /home instead of creating a new one.
This is not (nor is it intended to be) a dual-boot system.
Any advice would be welcome!

...so what is the format of that partition (probably /dev/sdc1)? Perhaps something is wrong with it, but you haven't posted any useful info to work with... :~)

From a live session, run sudo fdisk -l and sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL, copy and paste the outputs into the post

See this answer for how to do this during the installation of Ubuntu 22.04. The installer of 24.04 has changed, but the basic steps should be the same.

Thanks for the comments:
There was nothing wrong with the partition.
I am familiar with the 22.04 installation.  In fact I installed it the way it is shown in the instructions referred to by @user68186, keeping my /home from my 18.04 installation. In the 24.04 installation, there was no opportunity to select a /home. The installation simply proceeded once I had configured sda, creating a home directory under /.
I fixed the problem by using the live environment to add a line for /home to /etc/fstab on sda:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a3b46ff-fe33-4b5c-b3a3-5b96f247235e /home ext4 defaults 0 2

Thanks for all the help!
